# how to insert duplicate composite keys in onetomany default table in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, composite, hibernate-onetomany

The scenario is like: code table contains my master data which is independent from patient table but every patient requires to add multiple codes in them. The patient and codes table are joined unidirectionally by one-to-many relationship,
I want to insert multiple duplicate rows in my default one-to-many joined table but its giving

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch error

whenever it finds the duplicate code's foreign key.

### sample model of patient table:

```
private List<Codes> codes;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true) 

public List<Codes> getCodes() {
    return codes;
}

public void setCodes(List<Codes> codes) {
    this.codes = codes;
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vnI8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Joining tables are never declared and mapped in model and in hibernate configuration.

You must insert your initial datas directly in the database and if your mapping is done right when you'll save unidirectionally one to many objects, hibernate will add the row in the joining table.

Could you show the code you save the entity in ?

Comment: I have shown the code of patient entity in which i am saving the codes.

Comment: Sorry, i don't see any savings ?